# Configure http to https redirection in wildfly

Tags: ssl, jboss, wildfly-10, undertow

I have a myapp.war deployed on my Wildfly 10.1.0 server, All http request are redirected to https using the 8443 port.

Is there a configuration in Wildfly to make an exception for a specific URL ?

For example I'd like that http://localhost:8080/myapp/unprotected doesn't redirect to https://localhost:8443/myapp/unprotected.

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You specify security constraints as described in [The Java EE 6 Tutorial, Volume I](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19226-01/820-7627/bncbk/index.html).

One for the protected and one for the unprotected resources. For the latter you omit the `user-data-constraint`.